# C# GetHashCode/Equals override not called

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

I'm facing a problem with GetHashCode and Equals which I have overridden for a class. I am using the operator == to verify if both are equal and I'd expect this would be calling both GetHashCode and Equals if their hash code are the same in order to validate they are indeed equal.

But to my surprise, neither get called and the result of the equality test is false (while it should in fact be true).

Override code:

```
    public class User : ActiveRecordBase<User>

        [...]

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Id;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            User user = (User)obj;
            if (user == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return user.Id == Id;
        }
    }
```

Equality check:

```
    if (x == y) // x and y are both of the same User class
    // I'd expect this test to call both GetHashCode and Equals
```

Comment: If the `==` did in fact call your `Equals` method, then it would cause a stack overflow as it uses the `==` operator on the object...

Comment: There's nothing in the code you show that would indicate a need to call GetHashCode(). That's only called if you use your object as the key of a collection.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Operator `==` is completely separate from either `.GetHashCode()` or `.Equals()`.

You might be interested in the Microsoft [Guidelines for Overloading Equals() and Operator ==](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147.aspx).

The short version is:  Use `.Equals()` to implement **equality** comparisons.  Use operator `==` for **identity** comparisons, or if you are creating an immutable type (where every equal instance can be considered to be effectively identical).  Also, `.Equals()` is a virtual method and can be overridden by subclasses, but operator `==` depends on the compile-time type of the expression where it is used.

Finally, to be consistent, implement `.GetHashCode()` any time you implement `.Equals()`.  Overload operator `!=` any time you overload operator `==`.

Comment: My objects are mutable. I expected that calling the == operator would in fact call the Equals method, which I've seen working before, but I do not understand why it doesn't work now and it worked before...

Comment: @tomzx: The `==` operator never calls the `.Equals()` method unless you overload it to do so.

Comment: @Daniel  Your advice re "==" is incorrect. Microsoft consistently says that if you want IDENTITY comparison, you must use "ReferenceEquals". For example, consider strings. If you use string builder to make two strings that have same CONTENTS, but different ADDRESSES, then "==" will return TRUE (equality comparison), but ReferenceEquals will return FALSE. "==" is usually regarded as an EQUALITY comparison, and is usually implemented as doing whatever a class's EQUALS does.

Comment: Simple test:  ReferenceEquals(new String("abc"), new String("abc")) returns false. But ((new String("abc")) == (new String("abc"))) returns true. THEREFORE "==" is an EQUALITY comparison, not an IDENTITY comparison.  It merely happens to be the case that IF a class DOES NOT specify what "==" does, the DEFAULT behavior is to use ReferenceEquals.  Also consider VALUE objects, which obviously do an equality test for "==".

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: From the link in my answer: "When a type is immutable, that is, the data that is contained in the instance cannot be changed, overloading operator == to compare value equality instead of reference equality can be useful because, as immutable objects, they can be considered the same as long as they have the same value. It is not a good idea to override operator == in non-immutable types."  -- That implies to me that == should only behave like an equality operator in places where equality and identity can be safely conflated (that is, with immutable value-type-like values).

Comment: @Daniel the part of your answer I am concerned about is "Use operator == for identity comparisons". "identity" has a particular meaning in .Net. Under the hood, it means two identical pointers, to the same memory location. That is ReferenceEquals. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd183759.aspx  If you use the word "identity" differently than that, you risk confusing people. What you are discussing isn't identity, it is equivalence.

Comment: Specifically, two immutable objects with the same contents (but different objects; different locations in memory), do not have "the same identity", as .Net defines the term. Even though you are correct that they are identical; substituting one for the other should not alter the results of the program, if they are immutable.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: Ah, I understand your confusion now. My sentence was not attempting to define the meaning of "identity comparisons", which you correctly point out have an established meaning in .NET, but to offer two possible reasons to use `==`: **either** for an identity comparison, **or** for immutable objects.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps adding one more method in your `User` class.

```
    public virtual bool Equals(User other) 
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return other.Id == Id;
    }
```

Comment: don't you mean ```override``` instead of ```virtual``` ?